# MySQL return unique columname with 2 joins of equal table

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM scool
LEFT JOIN people as t1 ON t1.scool_fk=scool.id AND t1.lang_gk='en'
LEFT JOIN people as t2 ON t2.scool_fk=scool.id AND t2.lang_gk='fr'
```

...
(this is nonsense query, only for example)

With `SELECT *`  it query returns french values

With `SELECT t1.*`  it query returns english values

The only possible solution i know is

```
SELECT t1.name as name_en, t2.name as name_fr
```

This don't like me because i can't automatize the selects in my program

Is possible to be return all values from SELECT with tablename.columnname or other similar solution, for get values in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_field` and properties `table` and `name`:

```
<?php
        mysql_connect("", "", "");
        mysql_select_db("test");
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_ai a1 CROSS JOIN t_ai a2 LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
        $names = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($res); $i++) {
                $meta = mysql_fetch_field($res, $i);
                array_push($names, "$meta->table.$meta->name");
        }
        print implode($names, "\t") . "\n";
?>

$ php phptest.php
a1.id   a2.id
```

Comment: That won't actually help here, since the query joins on the same table twice.

Comment: @troelskn: Please look at the query and at the output.

Comment: With this I have columnames, but how i can get values of $res? is possible to modify mysql_result index names?

Comment: Its work great if you do mysql_fetch_num and relace index of $row for value of $names, thanks